# Switch does not change based on React.useState

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, antd

In this simple "demo" in CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-fast-fi426k?file=/src/App.tsx

you can see that `checked` actually changes, based on an external condition (inputted text length), but this does not "physically"change the Switch

```
    import "./styles.css";
    import * as React from "react";
    import { Switch } from "antd";
    import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
    
    export default function App() {
      const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
    
      let [checked, setChecked] = React.useState(false);
    
      const onSubmit = (data: string) => {
        console.log("data.text: ", data.text);
        let length = data.text.length;
        console.log("data.text.length: ", length);
        if (length > 5) {
          console.log("'checked' variable has to be set as TRUE");
          setChecked((checked) => true);
        } else {
          console.log("'checked' variable has to be set as FALSE");
          setChecked((checked) => false);
        }
      };
    
      const AntdOnChange = (checked) => {
        console.log(`switch to ${checked}`);
      };
    
      React.useEffect(() => {
        AntdOnChange(checked);
      }, [checked]);
    
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <div>
              <label htmlFor="text">Text</label>
              <input id="text" placeholder="text" {...register("text")} />
            </div>
    
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
          </form>
    
          <Switch
            checkedChildren="ON"
            unCheckedChildren="OFF"
            defaultChecked
            onChange={AntdOnChange}
          />
        </div>
      );
    }
```

How to pass the correctly changed value of checked variable to the Switch state ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by doing three things

1. Remove the useEffect that updates the checked state. If you pass the state into the switch component with that, it will cause multiple renders which will cause an error
2. Do this in your switch component. I have added the `checked` prop

```
 <Switch
        checkedChildren="ON"
        unCheckedChildren="OFF"
        defaultChecked
        checked={checked} 
        onChange={AntdOnChange}
      />
```

3. In your `AntdOnChange` function, do this. This function will work independently of whatever is added in the input

```
  const AntdOnChange = (checked) => {
    setChecked((checked) => !checked);
  };
```

Comment: Thank you. It works fine. I guess you added the `checked` prop, because otherwise the `checked` variable's values wouldn't have been seen by `Switch`. But I do not understand why you've set thet `AntdOnChange` function as a `"toggle function"`

Comment: From your question, you wanted both the switch and the input to control the state of the switch correct ? The switch is now a `controlled` component. the onchange method will serve as a way to sync the component `checked` prop with the switch's state